# managedQuery() vs context.getContentResolver.query() vs android.provider.something.query()

Tags: android

Pretty simple.
What is the difference among those three?

I want to list every Image in a device.
Should I use `managedQuery()`, `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.query()` or `context.getContentResolver.query()`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`managedQuery()` will use ContentResolver's query(). The difference is 
that with `managedQuery()` the activity will keep a reference to your 
Cursor and close it whenever needed (in `onDestroy()` for instance.) If 
you do `query()` yourself, you **will** have to manage the Cursor as a 
sensitive resource. If you forget, for instance, to `close()` it in 
`onDestroy()`, you will leak underlying resources (logcat will warn you 
about it.)

To query a content provider, you can use either the `ContentResolver.query()` method or the `Activity.managedQuery()` method. Both methods take the same set of arguments, and both return a Cursor object. However, `managedQuery()` causes the activity to manage the life cycle of the Cursor. A managed Cursor handles all of the niceties, such as unloading itself when the activity pauses, and requerying itself when the activity restarts. You can ask an Activity to begin managing an unmanaged Cursor object for you by calling `Activity.startManagingCursor()`.

**Update:**

`managedQuery` is now deprecated (as of Android 3.0).

Comment: @Pentium10: Great! And difference between using android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.query() and context.getContentResolver.query()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. Maybe there isn't.

Comment: Came for @Macarse's question :(

Comment: @Macarse There is no difference as the first param to android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.query() is a ContentResolver. The method is just an alias for context.getContentResolver.query().

Answer (score 23):

managedQuery(..) is now deprecated (as of Android 3.0). Watch out..

[Android error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915597/android-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-trying-to-requery-an-already-clos)