# Get Path of image from ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Hi I am using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` for capturing image using `Intent` as follows:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(
MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"))
);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

I need to store image in an sdcard and retrieve the path of that image using the `onActivityResult` method. I don't know how to get the image path of the currently captured image.

If any one knows please help.

Thanks

Comment: please put all of your code within the "code" textboxes, it makes reading your code much easier, so than we may be able to answer your questions

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is how it works on 2.2 (different than on previous versions). When starting intent

```
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);  
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT);
```

you need to remember `mCapturedImageURI`.

When you capture image, in `onActivityResult()` use that URI to obtain file path:

```
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
            int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
```

**UPDATE:** On new Android devices you would not need MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, but you rather deduce image/video URI from data.getData() received from onActivityResult(..., Intent data), as nicely described under

[Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent)

However, since this part is subject to manufacturer adaptation, you may still encounter phones where "old" approach may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for this, but does not work on Samsung Galaxy I or II. Returns thumbnail on HTC Incredible :-(

Comment: After taking the photo activity is reloaded & while starting my application, it shows "Waiting for Debugging....". Is anything I missed. Check the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510547/android-display-captured-image-in-img-tag

Comment: From onActivityResult() you may obtain what was the real name on the SD card. capturedImageFilePath has it.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Honestly, I am also not sure how does it work on all post 2.2 platforms, so any additional info is also valuable for me. Regards.

Comment: I got error in this code. What to pass CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT ?

Comment: @Zelimir : Can you please help me . I post my question here >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599201/get-error-when-capture-image

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara - I think you already got the answer in your new question track. CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT is in fact constant value (e.g. 1), used to distinguish this request from some other sent from your Activity. That constant should be used in the onActivityResult() callback.

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara - On which Android platform version are you running your code? Below 2.2 it works differently. Have you added permissions for Camera and writing of the xternal storage?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `managedQuery()` is deprecated now however, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7653634/1446598). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7469366/1446598) is a simple alternative; namely use `context.getContentResolver()` instead; where `context` is a `Context` instance.

Comment: but same image saves 2 time bydefault name and which we manually created file name

Answer (score 7):

Another way, tested on android 2.1, is take the ID or AbsolutePath of the gallery last image.

It can be done like that:

```
/**
 * Gets the last image id from the media store
 * @return
 */
private int getLastImageId(){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::id " + id);
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::path " + fullPath);
        imageCursor.close();
        return id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And to remove the file:

```
private void removeImage(int id) {
       ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[]{ Long.toString(id) } );
}
```

This code was based on the post: [Deleting a gallery image after camera intent photo taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken)

Answer (score 2):

This question is very old but I have been battling with the same problem for half a day. The issue is that your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent will always return `code=-1` and `data=null` unless you set the following permissions for the application in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

You can also set the following if you want to record audio from your application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Comment: After setting permission as well it gives code=-1 and data=null on nexus 4

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
```

and add

```
Uri uri = data.getData();in onActivityResult
```