# android camera and saving the images in sd card of android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application which involves saving images on click of click button in camera. How can i do it.... Thanks in advance Tushar Sahni

Comment: Have you read any Android documentation or books?

Comment: Yeah trojanfoe i have read but havenot got any good result yet??

Comment: Already asked several times. For example check answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184951/get-path-of-image-from-action-image-capture-intent/4185511#4185511

Answer (score 0):

Hey, have a look at this post, which may help: http://javablogs.com/Jump.action?id=618025
Documentation is talking a lot about manually implementing the Preview which is a pita and is massively confusing.

Comment: Ok,,,Heiko,,,, whats ur email id,,,Regards Tushar