# Android Camera - SD card unavailable

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Hi I'm using this to open up the native android camera application

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
this.startActivityForResult(camera, PHOTO);
```

When the device is connected to the computer I get "Please insert sd card before using the camera"

If it isn't connected it is fine.

Any ideas?

I figured it out. From the drag down menu you can tell your usb to only charge and that solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set debuggable mode in Applications - devlopment, if you are in USB mode, android will not allow you to use apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184951/get-path-of-image-from-action-image-capture-intent). There you maybe can change the save directory.