# error in onActivityResult method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-camera

I still have the same problem..

Java Code:

```
public void takePic() {
    String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
    mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

    cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Camera_requestCode);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Camera_requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        insertPath(capturedImageFilePath);
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
};
```

LogCat:

```
    03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo/com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at com.android.SaveCameraPictureDemo.SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity.onActivityResult(SaveCameraPictureDemoActivity.java:73)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
03-01 13:36:55.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20416):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output as well?

Comment: I posted but i dont know how to formate it well

Answer (score 1):

Below lines are wrong, you can't get path of captured image like this.

```
String imgPath = data.getData().toString();
        insertPath(imgPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

U will never get bitmap from other activity. thats ur Problem
why don't you simply pass the path of the image and let the second activity decide what to do with that path (decode and display the image, in this case).

Comment: so what ?u must be saving that image in sd card ?

Comment: can u give me an example please

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184951/get-path-of-image-from-action-image-capture-intent for more details