# How to get full size bitmap from camera?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera-intent

I have used intent to launch camera

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent( 
android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
getParent().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

and onActivityResult() used

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
Save_to_SD (thumbnail, filename);
```

But get thumbnail was small size, how do I get the full bitmap?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184951/get-path-of-image-from-action-image-capture-intent

Comment: i tried Uri,but it return some time late.that time show black screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save output to some uri and get it from there

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                mImageCaptureUri1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri1);                     
                cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```