# how to get full size image on camera Intent

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I want to get Full size image from `camera` `intent`.I have tried bellow code but i getting image size very small.following is my code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent , PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2);
```

`onActivityResult` code

```
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST2)
    {
        //filePath = data.getData();
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv_upload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        check=true;

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        filePath = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: this has been answered multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo?rq=1  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700731/how-to-get-full-size-bitmap-from-camera?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing this you get the thumb preview as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

```
 data.getExtras().get("data");
```

If you want the full size, you need to create a collision-resistant file name and invoke your intent like this

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                          "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                          photoFile);

takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Here's the [full example](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Comment: yes,its work for me.Thanks

Comment: @ajaydhadhal Do you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: yes i accept this answer.

Comment: and i upvote this answer :)

Comment: too fast, how do i use the file? @@

Comment: @user2297550 you can declare **Uri photoURI** in the class scope and use it after onActivityResult to be invoked