# How to retrieve the image path of the new taken picture in android?

Tags: android

I start a cam intent and want to retrieve the picture path of the new taken picture in my app. How can I achieve this? I need the path of this picture so that my background service can work with it.

```
else if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == ActionActivity.RESULT_OK){
    Log.i(ACTION_ACTIVITY_TAG, "picture intent gives result ok");
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putSerializable("picUri", ??????);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtras(b);
    i.setClass(this,CommentActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: post your camera starting code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4185511/1777090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to use `putSerializable` for sending URI of taken image from camera just retrieve uri from intent in `onActivityResult` and send it as String to another Activity :

```
else if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == ActionActivity.RESULT_OK){
    Log.i(ACTION_ACTIVITY_TAG, "picture intent gives result ok");
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    Uri picuri = intent.getData();
    b.putString("picUri", picuri.toString());

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtras(b);
    i.setClass(this,CommentActivity.class);
```

and in `CommentActivity` Activity you can retrieve pic URI as :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

imguri = extras.getString("picUri");
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imguri);
```