# How to get thumbnail and image path from android camera?

Tags: android, android-intent

by this way

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

i get a bitmap form intent in the onActivityResult, and not the path !, by this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

i can get the path from intent, and not the bitmap !!, how can i get the bitmap(thumbnail) and the path from android camera ?

Comment: Check these questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591825/how-to-get-image-path-just-captured-from-camera 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322670/how-to-get-image-path-from-camera-intent 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-path-of-image-on-android 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636697/get-path-and-filename-from-camera-intent-result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that you can get the image path with using that path create a thumbnail image like this

```
/**
 * 
 * Returns the given size of the bitmap
 * 
 * @param path
 * @return {@link Bitmap}
 */
private Bitmap getThumbnailBitmap(String path, int thumbnailSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
        return null;
    }
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / thumbnailSize;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
}
```

give the size how much you want

Comment: mmmmm nice, thanks for your answer .. :) but how about that thumbnailSize parameter ? what is that ? is it about width & height ?

Comment: what parameter do i have to set if i want a 100dp x 100dp thumbnail of image ???????????

Comment: I have set thumb size as 400 and its returning blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I've used this in an app and this will work perfect,

```
static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
String name =   dateToString(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

In your OnActivityResult()

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) { 
       Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

       //Here photo is your bitmap image, use this as per your requirement
```

Comment: and we're not get the image path ?

Comment: for now i still try the solution from @kalyanpvs , i'll try it later .. :)

Comment: my `data` is null (inside onActivityResult). :(