# How is it possible to get the path from the activity result of a `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`?

Tags: java, android

I created an activity, which takes a photo using the default camera app. I used the code from this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath

I create the intent like this:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And then I set the path of the output:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, currentPhotoPath);
```

In the tutorial, they save `currentPhotoPath` to a private variable in the activity. I would like to avoid that, and get the path from the intent in the `onActivityResult` function, here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // How to access the path here?
    }
}
```

I tried `intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)`, but it returns null.

I would like to avoid storing the path in a class member, because the activity might be destroyed and recreated by the android system, and then that variable will be null.

I was able to find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184951/get-path-of-image-from-action-image-capture-intent), but the answers are for Android 2, and they use deprecated apis, like `managedQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to avoid that, and get the path from the intent in the onActivityResult function, here

That is not possible, sorry. It would require rewriting every camera app.

> I would like to avoid storing the path in a class member, because the activity might be destroyed and recreated by the android system, and then that variable will be null.

Save it in the saved instance state `Bundle`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) is a bit old, but it demonstrates the basic technique. Save the `File` in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```java
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }
```

...and get it back in `onCreate()`, if the passed-in `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` is not `null`:

```java
output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
```