# Android ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter - Crashes onResume

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` in `AcitivityA` that is populated using a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` called `RecipeAdapter`. The adapter holds data from `SQLite`

There is a `EditText` view at the top of the `ListView`, that filters the listview as the user searches for a recipe. When a user clicks on a item in the filtered `ListView`, `ActivityB` starts.

This all works perfectly. However when the user presses the backbutton to resume `ActivityB`, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@418af170
```

My attempts at fixing the problem:

- Duplicating code from the `onCreate()` to the `onResume` method.
- Adding `c.requery()` to `onResume()` method
- Adding `db.close` to `onDestroy()` method

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Here is my code:

In the `onCreate`, the `cursor` populate the `ListView` using `c.getCursor` and when the user filters the `ListView` via the `EditText`, the `c.getFilterCursor` is used.

```
public class RecipeActivity extends SherlockListActivity {

private DBHelper db = null;
private Cursor c = null;
private RecipeAdapter adapter = null;
ListView listContent;   
private EditText filterText = null;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter_list);

        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

        ListView listContent = getListView();

        db = new DBHelper(this);
        db.createDataBase();
        db.openDataBase();

        c = db.getCursor();         

        adapter = new RecipeAdapter(c);

        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                // Search for states whose names begin with the specified letters.
                c = db.getFilterCursor(constraint);
                return c;
            }
        });

        startManagingCursor(c);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);


    }

};
```

RecipeAdapter inner class

```
class RecipeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public RecipeAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(RecipeActivity.this, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View row, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {
        RecipeHolder holder = (RecipeHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, db);

    }

    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reciperow, arg2, false);
        RecipeHolder holder = new RecipeHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);

        return (row);
    }


static class RecipeHolder {
    public TextView id = null;
    private TextView name = null;
    private TextView desc = null;
    private TextView preptime = null;
    private TextView cooktime = null;
    private TextView serves = null;
    private TextView calories = null;
    private TextView fat = null;
    private TextView fav = null;

    RecipeHolder(View row) {
        id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.recipe);
        desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        preptime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.preptime);
        cooktime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cooktime);
        serves = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.serving);
        calories = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calories);
        fat = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fat);
        fav = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fav);
    }


    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DBHelper r) {
        id.setText(r.getId(c));
        name.setText(r.getRecipe(c));
        name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CCf27c22"));
        desc.setText(r.getDesc(c));
        preptime.setText(r.getPrepTime(c) + ". ");
        cooktime.setText(r.getCookTime(c) + " mins");
        serves.setText(r.getServes(c));
        calories.setText(r.getCalories(c));
        fat.setText(r.getFat(c));
        fav.setText(r.getFav(c));
```

getCursor() and getFilterCursor() code from DBHelper class

```
public Cursor getCursor() {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, RECIPE, DESC, PREPTIME,
            COOKTIME, SERVES, CALORIES, FAT, CATEGORY, FAV };

    Cursor myCursor = queryBuilder.query(myDataBase, columns, null, null,
            null, null, RECIPE + " ASC");

    return myCursor;
}




public Cursor getFilterCursor(CharSequence constraint) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, RECIPE, DESC, PREPTIME,
            COOKTIME, SERVES, CALORIES, FAT, CATEGORY, FAV };

    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
        // Return the full list
        return queryBuilder.query(myDataBase, columns, null, null, null,
                null, RECIPE + " ASC");
    } else {
        String value = "%" + constraint.toString() + "%";

        return myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "RECIPE like ? ",
                new String[] { value }, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

FULL LOGCAT

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ttj.android.quorn/ttj.android.quorn.RecipeActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41954658
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41954658
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4508)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
```

Comment: Please post your all of the LogCat errors and indicate the line where the last error happens.

Comment: @Sam Logcat included in question now.

Comment: Since you are opening your database in onCreate(), you ought to add `db.close()` in onDestroy(). What is the code for `db.getCursor()`?

Comment: @Sam I have added `db.close()` to `onDestroy()` and this makes no difference. Sharing `getCursor()` code now.

Comment: Using `db.close()` is just good practice. By the way, that is a **great** use of newView() and bindView(), you're not just blindly overriding getView(). However I cannot make sense of your LogCat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wha't the version of Android platform you are running your application? This method startManagingCursor is deprecated since Honeycomb. Developers are suggested to use the new CursorLoader class with LoaderManager instead, which is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

Actually I got the same problem on Honeycomb. However I didn't follow above instructions as I don't have much time to rewrite my code. So here is my solution, I hope it helps. But if you have time, you should switch to use CursorLoader and LoaderManager which gains much better performance.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //do the query again every time on resume
    Cursor c = mExpenseDb.queryCategories(mSettings.getCurrentAccount().getId());
    //mAdapter is a SimpleCursorAdapter, set its cursor to the new one 
    mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //mAdapter is a SimpleCursorAdapter, invalidate its data and set it cursor to null on Activity pause
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

    mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: I will give this a shot when I get home tonight. Should I modify my `onCreate()` at all?

Comment: I get an error `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 70`. My list has 70 items. I have `cursor.moveToFirst()` in my `getCursor()` in `DBHelper.class` but the stop exception occurs.

Comment: @tiptopjat Sorry, I was on business trip so I didn't get a chance to answer you quesiton. Here is my suggestion. Do dbHelper and cursorAdaptor initialization in the onCreate() method and the do db query and change cursor in the onResume() method. Regarding to CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException, it should not happen if you call cursor.moveToFirst() in advance. Can you share you updated code if possible? thanks. -Jay