# What is the difference between MediaStore.Images.Media.query() and ContentResolver.query()

Tags: android

I have seen both of these in use. I know, they are both query methods as in with respect to a `ContentProvider` but what is the basic difference between the two? Is the difference, a performance difference if nothing else?

Comment: please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595306/4448617

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714701/deprecated-managedquery-issue

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595213/managedquery-vs-context-getcontentresolver-query-vs-android-provider-somethi
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595213/managedquery-vs-context-getcontentresolver-query-vs-android-provider-somethi/2595306#2595306